# Binary Search Tree serialization formatting

Tags: javascript, algorithm, serialization, binary-search-tree

I have created a function to serialize a binary sort tree. I am traversing the tree in preorder, so `Root -> Left -> Right` and building a string recursively.

```
function serialize(root, str = '') {
    if (root !== undefined) {
        str += root.data + ', ' + serialize(root.left) + serialize(root.right);
        return str;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

My output is `"8, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 10, 14, 13, "` and I am trying to figure out a way to remove the trailing `,` and `whitespace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check to see if your node has a left or right leaf before recursively calling `serialize` on it and it fixes your issue.

```
function serialize(root, str = '') {
    if (root) {
        str += root.data;
        if (root.left) {
            str += ', ' + serialize(root.left);
        }
        if (root.right) {
            str += ', ' +  serialize(root.right);
        }
    } 
    return str;
}
```

Comment: What would be a good way to go about doing these solutions while keeping everything in the same function? The recursive part seems to interfere.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.trim()` to remove `whitespace` and `,`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

You have to first remove the last whitespace using [str.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) and then remove last comma by [str.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Below is complete working code:

```js
var str = "8, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 10, 14, 13, ";

str = str.trim();

console.log(str.substring(0, str.length - 1));
```